# Is the Higgs particle the final one predicted by the Standard Model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, higgs

Are there any other particle predictions by the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Higgs boson in LHC](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45203/)

Comment: The Standard Model has just one Higgs.

Comment: I had VTCed as "Unclear what you' are asking", actually. I'm a bit annoyed when the system puts VTC reasons in my mouth.

Comment: Why duplicate? I searched Google for my question and nothing showed up. Do you expect people with a similar question as mines to search for "Higgs boson in LHC"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that we have seen the Higgs boson, all the particles predicted by the Standard Model have been discovered.

The penultimate particle to be discovered was the tau-neutrino at Fermi-Lab in 2000. The antepenultimate particle to be discovered was the top quark, also at Fermi-Lab in 1995. For a complete timeline, see e.g. [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_particle_discoveries).

There are, of course, theories that predict even more particles (so-called Beyond the Standard Model physics), but no such particles have been directly observed.

Comment: +1, though you should add that there *have* been some signs of supersymmetric particles, and that the 125 GeV Higgs is also an indicator of Supersymmetry/MSSM/M-Theory compactifications.

Comment: @DIMension10 why is a 125 GeV Higgs an indication to correctness of those theories? Please provide references.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: See Reference 4, Reference 23, Reference 24, Reference 25, Reference 26, Reference 27, Reference 28, and Referencee 29, [here](http://psiepsilon.wikia.com/wiki/String_Theory#References). Specifically, Reference 4.

Comment: @DIMension10 what indications of supersymmetric particles? Experimental hints? $g-2$? DM?

Comment: @innisfree: See [here.](http://psiepsilon.wikia.com/wiki/String_Theory#Of_Supersymmetry)

Comment: There are no compelling hints of supersymmetric particles in data so far, and no strong sense in which a 125 GeV Higgs constitutes evidence for supersymmetry. The fact that certain supersymmetric theories with a split spectrum predict a Higgs mass near 125 GeV is interesting, and we should certainly be looking for experimental evidence of such theories, but there is no evidence so far. The Standard Model with a 125 GeV Higgs is a consistent, but highly fine-tuned, theory.